# Code Snippet Shortcuts VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need some small information about visual studio. Presently, I am using VS 2010. When we type **"ctor + tab + tab"**, it will create code snippet for **"Constructor"** if the language Visual C#. Similarly, for prop,//,etc...

But, its not the case with VB.NET language. Can you guys provide some list of shortcuts which VS(VB.NET) supports.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "ctor" is C# speak, the code snippets in VB.NET have very different keywords.  Find out what is there by starting with Edit + IntelliSense + Insert Snippet.  I never use it but I don't think there's one for a constructor.  Not much to gain from "Sub New".

Answer (score 1):

[Code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188694.aspx) are highly customizable code fragments intended to accomplish simple to intermediate tasks quickly; they can be inserted into your code with just a few keystrokes.

You can insert [IntelliSense Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165399%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) using the Code Snippet Picker or typing the shortcut name of the snippet and pressing Tab. When you know the name of the snippet you want to insert, you can do so by typing its shortcut followed by the TAB key. When you have to browse for an appropriate snippet, you can use the snippet picker, which gives you categorized lists of snippets to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic includes a code library consisting of several hundred pieces of code, called [IntelliSense code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx), that are ready to be inserted in your application. Each snippet performs a complete programming task such as creating a custom exception, sending an e-mail message, or drawing a circle. You can insert a snippet into your source code with a few mouse clicks. You can also create your own snippets that suit your business needs, add them to the library, and then use them when needed.